# Undefined variable block...when trying to integrate a form into a block

Tags: forms

i was just beginning to build my first module which should display a checkbox in a block.

With this code (see below) I get an Error:
Notice: Undefined variable: block in ios_lang_checkbox_block_view()

```
<?php
function ios_lang_checkbox_menu() {
    $items['ios'] = array(
        'title' => 'View the sample form',
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => array('ios_lang_checkbox_nameform'),
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM
    );
    return $items;
}

/**
 * Define a form.
 */
function ios_lang_checkbox_nameform() {
    $options = array(
        'de' => t('de'),
        );
    $form['ios'] = array(
        '#title' => t('Your Name'),
        '#type' => 'checkboxes',
        '#description' => t('Choose language'),
        '#options' => $options,
    );
    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Submit')
    );
    return $form;
}
function ios_lang_checkbox_block_view($delta='')
{
  switch($delta) {
    case 'ios_lang_checkbox':
      $block['subject'] = null; // Most forms don't have a subject 
      $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('ios_lang_checkbox_form_function');
      break;
   }
   return $block;
 }

?>
```

Any help with that?

Comment: There seems to be at least two functions missing from that code (`ios_lang_checkbox_block_info()` and `ios_lang_checkbox_form_function()`) could you post those as well?

Comment: @Clive the are no...so mybe thats where the problem comes from ;-P

Comment: I think so yeah :P I'll chuck some ideas in an answer

Comment: thanx a lot...!

Comment: i added this: function ios_lang_checkbox_block_info() {
    $blocks = array();
    $blocks['ios_switcher'] = array(
        'info' => t('IOS Lang Checkbox'),
        'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
    );
    return $blocks;
} but error keeps the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for `hook_block_view()` to work properly you also need to implement [`hook_block_info()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7), which in your case would look something like this:

```
function ios_lang_checkbox_block_info() {
  return array(
    'ios_lang_checkbox' => array(
      'info' => t('Block Name'),
      'description' => t('Block description')
    )
  );
}
```

That will register a block called `ios_lang_checkbox`, which will become the `$delta` var when your implementation of `hook_block_view()` is invoked.

At the moment, when that function executes there's no `$delta` available (since one hasn't been defined), and hence `$block` is undefined when you return it. Usually one would write `$block = array()` at the start of the function to avoid this, but in your case that would actually just have masked the problem.

The signature for your form function is slightly wrong, that needs to be:

```
function ios_lang_checkbox_nameform($form, &$form_state) {
```

It won't actually affect anything on a form that simple, but it's a good practice to get into...eventually it will come back to bite you if you don't!

The other small issue is the name of the form function you're calling inside `hook_block_view()`...I suspect you mean it to be the same form that's available from the path defined in `hook_menu()`, in which case that line should be:

```
$block['content'] = drupal_get_form('ios_lang_checkbox_nameform');
```

Once you've made the changes, make sure to clear Drupal's caches...otherwise your new hook implementation won't get picked up.

Comment: great help thanks a lot...such a hard learing curve all this api stuff...

Comment: Yeah it really is, I've been programming with Drupal for about 2.5 years and I'm still learning new stuff all the time. Persevere though, it's definitely worth it :)

Comment: ;-P I hope so...I really enjoy the front and drag and drop tough...my client wants to have a language switcher thats looks like a ios on-off switcher...grrr next thing will be to save to state of the checkbox...but thats gonna be my work for tomorrow i guess ;-P